# How to split Chinese words and English words in a string using python?

Tags: python, string, nlp

For example, I have some strings look like:

`'人均收入 Per capital Income'`,

`'总产值 Gross Output Value'`.

I want to split them into

`'人均收入' 'Per capital Income'`

`'总产值' 'Gross Output Value'`

Chinese characters are always before English words.

Comment: If there is some useful answer,consider to accept it by checking the mark beside the answer.Refer to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

If there is always a single span of Chinese text, you can just split on the first space:

```
s.split(' ', 1)
```

If there may be spaces within the Chinese text, you can look for the first ASCII character which is not space:

```
for ii, ch in enumerate(s): 
    if not ch.isspace() and ch.isascii():
        break
```

When that loop completes, it leaves `ii` set to the index of the first ASCII character which is not a space.  You can turn it into a function like and do the splitting like this:

```
def split_ascii(s): 
    for ii, ch in enumerate(s): 
        if not ch.isspace() and ch.isascii(): 
            break 
    return s[:ii].rstrip(), s[ii:]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try regex:

```
import re

s = '人均收入 Per capital Income'
result = re.match(r"([\u4e00-\u9fa5]*)([A-Za-z\s]*)", s)
print(result.group(1)) # 人均收入
print(result.group(2)) #  Per capital Income
```

Answer (score 1):

To me is so hard to work with regex.
I prefer to do this option:

```
import string
i = 0
CHINESE = ''
ENGLISH = ''
while i < len('人均收入 Per capital Income'):
  if '人均收入 Per capital Income'[i] in string.ascii_letters:
    break
  i += 1
CHINESE = '人均收入 Per capital Income'[:i-1]
ENGLISH = '人均收入 Per capital Income'[i:]
```

Comment: It should be `'人均收入 Per capital Income'[:i-1]` and `'人均收入 Per capital Income'[I:]`