# Seperate hundreds of English and Chinese vocabularies to a table

Tags: python, excel, split, word-list

I'm trying to use python to separate an entire text file that is something like this:

```
Above Ground 地面上 AG Abutment 橋臺 ABUT Acceptance Quality Level 可接受品質水準 AQL Acoustical 隔音 ACOUS Adit 隧道橫坑 Advanced Shoring Method 支撐先進工法
```

So the format is {Chinese word} _ {English word}_.

```
Ex: ABUT Acceptance Quality Level 可接受品質水準
```

(_ is for blank)

I want to conver them to a table with one row of English and another row of Chinese [Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOP1X.png)

Is there any way to do it with numpy or regex? Or are there some other easy alternatives (like excel)?
Thank you!

**Edit:**
I tried with this code, but there's a traceback.

```
import re

path = 'wordlist.txt'
file = open(path, "r")
result = re.match(r"([\u4e00-\u9fa5]*)([A-Za-z\s]*)", file)
print(result.group(1)) 
print(result.group(2))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\...\Desktop\web dev\parsetextforQuizlet\sepretatchiEng.py", line 5, in <module>
    result = re.match(r"([\u4e00-\u9fa5]*)([A-Za-z\s]*)", file)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 191, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Lots of posts about separating texts, which ones have you already considered and discarded so we don’t waste our time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62724446/how-to-split-chinese-words-and-english-words-in-a-string-using-python I checked this one, its quite similar to mine however I have no idea how to convert the code given to export into a table

Comment: Instead of a table, just a list in two columns?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/62724446/4961700

Comment: Yes just listing it to two columns also works. That post is what I have just seen I thought it only prints them out as one sentence ill try it out again

Comment: So do another search for splitting text - several on here, but I won't check out any more as you seem to have them.